# Javascript usage of delete increases RAM usage and execution time

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, memory, benchmarking

I implemented a benchmark using [js-meter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-meter) and compared the array methods `map` and `forEach` on parsing some data. **See my script below.**

**Scenario:**
E.g. if we get a huge array from an API and just want to instantiate a `Date` object based on a given timestamp for each item and want to get rid of some unnecessary properties.

**Two things are very strange to me:**

1. Using `map()` as seen in the script should create a totally new array with new objects. So the memory usage should be the double, but isn't.
2. Using `delete` inside the loop (`map`, `forEach`, `for`) is increasing the memory usage and time spent by ~3 times. Why is using delete so bad here?

**Additional Info:**
I ran the tests separately (just commented all out except one) on a MacBook Pro with macOS Catalina with Node version 10.15.3

```js
const jm = require('js-meter');

const isPrint = true;
const isKb = true;       // or Mb
const m = new jm({isPrint, isKb});
const printItemIndex = 45;
const arr = [];
const now = Date.now();

//  Create an array with some fake example data.
for(let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    const delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);    
    arr.push({
        index: i,
        delay,
        timestamp: now
  });
}

//  Map the array and turn a timestamp to a Date
//  Result of Benchmark: 33 MB RAM, 58ms
console.log("\n\nTest 1 with .map()");
const result = arr.map(data => {
    return {
        delay: data.delay,
        date: new Date(data.timestamp + data.delay)
    };
});

//  Use forEach and save weak copy to result array
//  Result of Benchmark: 91 MB RAM, 127ms
console.log("\n\nTest 2 with .forEach()");
arr.forEach(data => {
  data.date = new Date(data.timestamp + data.delay)
  delete data.index;
  delete data.timestamp;
});
const result = arr;

//  Map the array and turn a timestamp to a Date
//  Result of Benchmark: 83 MB RAM, 140ms
console.log("\n\nTest 3 with .map() and a delete");
const result = arr.map(data => {
    delete data.index;
    return {
        delay: data.delay,
        date: new Date(data.timestamp + data.delay)
    };
});

//  Use forEach and save weak copy to result array
//  Result of Benchmark: 32 MB RAM, 45ms
console.log("\n\nTest 4 with .forEach() w/o delete");
arr.forEach(data => {
  data.date = new Date(data.timestamp + data.delay);
});
const result = arr;

//  Use forEach and save weak copy to result array
//  Result of Benchmark:  32 MB RAM, 46ms
console.log("\n\nTest 5 with for loop");
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {    
    arr[i].date = new Date(arr[i].timestamp + arr[i].delay);
}
const result = arr;

//  Use forEach and save weak copy to result array
//  Result of Benchmark: 92 MB RAM, 145ms
console.log("\n\nTest 6 with for loop");
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {    
    arr[i].date = new Date(arr[i].timestamp + arr[i].delay);
    delete arr[i].index;
    delete arr[i].timestamp;
}
const result = arr;

m.stop();
```